# How do I change the front-end default language? 1.7.0.2

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, language, default

**How do I change the default language?  Front-End only**.

- CE 1.7.0.2
- Entering the website address gives the store Home page in English.
- Preference of local French Home page/Accueil as default.
- Admin needs to stay in English.
- The language switcher is working great.

  *Thank you in advance for pointing me in the right direction.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old without an accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that your home page is selected in the correct language:

Go to > System -> Configuration -> Web

Under the heading "Default Pages" there is a "CMS Home Page" drop down item.

Select the CMS page that is in the default language you would like to display when visitors enter your website.

Ensure that the CMS page is in fact the correct language.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System->Configuration->General->Locale Options` and set the value for `Locale` to `English(United States)`.
Then select you website from the top left store selector.
And set the value for the same field to `French(France)`.
Clear the cache and you are done.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but the default language on the frontend is still english, and now I get french in the admin. This is the opposite of what I was trying to do.

Comment: This is strange. I've always done it the way I described it. If you say it's the other way around, then do it the other way around. But first make sure you cleared the cache.